# Read a HTTP-header while making an API call from Excel VBA using JSON

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, vba

I am making API-calls to a server from Excel VBA by using this JsonConverter:

*) https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

I use this commands which works fine:

`http.Open "GET", APIString, False http.send     Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)`

however an API that I am using the authentication token in the Header of the return and the responseText only returns the body.

does anyone know how to return the header

Comment: Have considered using the `getAllResponseHeaders` method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object? It returns a string containing all the response headers

Comment: Take your focus away from the JsonConverter. It is not relevant to your problem. The http calls (which is what you want to look at) are made prior to the conversion made by the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the HTTP headers of the response by using `getAllResponseHeaders`. This method returns a string containing all the response headers. You can parse that response to extract the value you like.
You can slightly edit your code to capture the headers :

```vb
http.Open "GET", APIString, False
http.send
headers = http.getAllResponseHeaders
' Parse headers to extract the value of the header you are interested in
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
```